# IN clause using active record query base in order to create list of integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to replicate some SQL functionality using ActiveRecord. My problem relates to my use of a the ruby join method (not be confused with a SQL join). Here is my code:

```
scope :stats_tips_given, lambda { |date|
  where("created_at >= ? AND tipper_id IN(?)",date, User.stats_users(date).collect(&:id).join(', '))
  }
```

However the resultant sql query has this result:  `SELECT "tip_events".* FROM "tip_events" WHERE (created_at >= '2011-04-14' AND tipper_id IN('4, 5, 11, 17, 22, 48, 54, 65, 88, 103, 147, 151, 181, 182, 189, 195, 190, 196, 202, 226, 227, 231, 243, 245, 232, 225, 212, 217, 220, 263, 265, 273, 281, 282, 284, 286, 293, 271, 299, 300, 309, 310, 312, 318, 321, 308, 303, 297, 333, 346, 362, 368, 377, 386, 389, 392, 353, 398, 427, 420, 434, 418, 454, 456, 477, 484, 480, 453, 450, 452, 458, 497, 498, 503, 510, 511, 515, 522, 529, 537, 540, 508, 499, 524, 521, 502, 542, 546, 548, 557, 559, 571, 575, 576, 581, 587, 562, 580, 544, 567, 565, 573, 577, 597, 606, 619, 620, 640, 636, 607, 603, 600, 596, 656, 657, 668, 676, 683, 685, 662, 677, 669, 689, 678, 690, 694, 514, 206, 304, 601, 63, 495, 150, 344, 691, 490, 545, 634, 222, 288, 534, 630, 569, 323, 697, 489, 394, 568, 661, 672, 130, 381, 590, 205, 527, 474, 184, 622'))`

This query would be fine if it didn't have the single quote around the list of numbers. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're forming a string by using `join`. Just pass it the actual array instead:

```
User.stats_users(date).collect(&:id)
```

Instead of:

```
User.stats_users(date).collect(&:id).join(', ')
```